# Cython vector operations

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, vector, cython

How can I use the `remove` function from `<algorithm>`?  (Or any other operation, I want to use this with vectors, I tried to `cdef extern` to declare it, but there is no template function yet, I think)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cython can only reasonably link against compiled code in some external library following the C calling conventions.  To use template functions, you'll have to write an `extern "C"` wrapper function that uses a specific incarnation of the algorithm (i.e. you have to fix the template parameters).

Comment: Thank you. Thats a nice way. But in this case I can´t use cython cdef classes as templates (i.e. cdef vector[MyCdefClass] vec), right? 
Maybe with *PyObject but there is a loss of performance in this way.(Uses python table lookup)

Comment: @Patric: As far as I am aware, there is no really easy way to wrap a `std::vector` for use in Python using Cython.

Comment: We have this: `from libcpp.vector cimport vector`.
And we can do things like this 
`cdef class Obj:pass;
cdef vector[Obj] vec;
vec.push_back(Obj());`.

Comment: @Patric: My knowledge of Cython is a bit dated.  I wasn't aware of `libcpp` at all, so probably I can't help you a lot on this one.  If there are still questions remaining, ask a new SO question.